# Select Id when only one part is known

Tags: jquery

I have different div generated dynamically with an ID like : `common_NUMBER`. Number is different for each div.

I'd like to create an event on the div using their IDs, like :

```
$('#common_').on('click',function(){

});
```

How can I select dynamically all the `div#common` for all NUMBER's values ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
$('div[id^="common_"]').on('click',function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Mark it as your answer if it solved your problem. It will help others too who are looking for similar things.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify your selector as,

```
$("div[id^=common_]")
```

Which will select all `div` elements whose `id` attribute starts with *common_*.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ms117L3/)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers answer the specific question asked, but for other cases, check out the [jQuery selectors page](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) which has the following information:

Check for an attribute where it contains something:

```
jQuery( "[attribute*='value']" )
```

Check for an attribute where it status with something:

```
jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )
```

Check for an attribute when it ends with something:

```
jQuery( "[attribute$='value']" )
```

There's a load of other things you might want to do, such as not equal to `jQuery( "[attribute!='value']" )` and more.